# How to route the traffic from machine 1 to machine 3 via machine 2 and vice versa, on the same subnet?

Tags: linux, routing, xen, private-network

I've a Citrix Xenserver where I'm running VMs. I have three VMs there, and they have 2 NICs each: `eth0` is my company LAN which I'm using for management, and `eth1` is a "single-server private network" on all three VMs. The management interface is just for my SSH sessions.

The IPs assigned to my VMs are:

```
M1 = 192.168.0.1/24
M2 = 192.168.0.2/24
M3 = 192.168.0.3/24
```

On M2, I've got IP forwarding enabled:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

To route the traffic via M2 from M1 to M3:

```
ip route add 192.168.0.3 via 192.168.0.2 dev eth1
```

Likewise on M3:

```
ip route add 192.168.0.1 via 192.168.0.2 dev eth1
```

But when I traceroute or send traffic from M1 to M3 (or vice versa), it seems to be going straight to the destination instead of going through M2. Is it because they are on the same subnet? If they are on the same subnet, what should be done on my Linux machine to achieve this routing?

Comment: Why do you need routing for that? Actually, when you do `ifconfig up` on your VM, it automatically adds pseudo route like `192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0` -- no router involved.

Comment: There's an application sitting there on M2 which needs to intercept packets going to and from M1 and M3, and do its stuff. I'm trying to simulate such a setup on VMs.

Comment: Than create two bridges/virtual switches, put M1 and one iface of M2 to first and second iface of M2 along with M3 to another switch, create two subnetworks and make M2 real router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Networks:

1. Create a single-server private network on Xen.
2. Add it machine1 and machine3, one each.
3. Add ***two of them created at step 1 to machine2***.

### Machine1:

```
ip addr add 1.1.1.2/24 dev eth1
ip route add 2.2.2.0/24 via 1.1.1.1 dev eth1 proto static
```

### Machine3:

```
ip addr add 2.2.2.2/24 dev eth1
ip route add 1.1.1.0/24 via 2.2.2.1 dev eth1 proto static
```

### Machine2 (router):

```
ip addr add 1.1.1.1/24 dev eth1
ip addr add 2.2.2.1/24 dev eth2
```

### Testing:

```
ping 2.2.2.2 # machine1
ping 1.1.1.2 # machine3
```